# When patching, assert_called_once not failing when it should

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

In python unittest it says mock.assert_called_once() will fail if it is called more than once. When patching I am not seeing that behavior.

ugh.py

```
def foo(*args):
    pass

def bar():
    foo(1)
    foo(2)
```

tests.py

```
from unittest import TestCase, main
from unittest.mock import patch
from ugh import bar

class Test(TestCase):

    @patch('ugh.foo')
    def test_called_once(self, foo_mock):
        bar()
        foo_mock.assert_called_once()

    @patch('ugh.foo')
    def test_called_count_one(self, foo_mock):
        bar()
        self.assertEqual(foo_mock.call_count, 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And test output.

```
razorclaw% python tests.py
F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_called_count_one (__main__.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1142, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "tests.py", line 15, in test_called_count_one
    self.assertEqual(foo_mock.call_count, 1)
AssertionError: 2 != 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Using python 3.4.6 on linux

Answer (score 1):

`assert_called_once` doesn't exist in 3.4. It didn't exist until 3.6. If you are on 3.4 you can use `assert_called_once_with`

Comment: It *is* [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_once) as new in 3.6. In 3.4 there is no `assert_called_once` behaviour, you're just calling a mocked method like any other.

Comment: I have modified my answer. One unfortunate gotcha with pythons mocking flexibility.

Comment: In 3.5 it's an `AttributeError`, as any method starting `assert_` but not implemented seems to be.

Answer (score 0):

Run the test like this:

```
python -m unittest tests
```